# Camel route xpath filter

Tags: java, xpath, apache-camel

i m stuck with xpath filter in camel route, and i don t find solution...

here is my xml message

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:ct="http://com/fr/test">
<env:Header>
    <receptionTime xmlns="http://com/fr/test">2016-02-12T14:40:56+0100
    </receptionTime>
    <correlationId xmlns="http://com/fr/test">944689bc-9605-4292-929a-3b2e8a5eddd7
    </correlationId>
    <equipmentType xmlns="http://com/fr/test">WCA</equipmentType>
    <messageType xmlns="http://com/fr/test">Reservation</messageType>
</env:Header>
<env:Body>
<content xmlns="http://com/fr/test"></content>
</env:Body>
```

and my route lokk like this :

```
 from("activemq-ext-in:queue:" + queueName)
    .id("amq-transfert-downward-route")
    .filter().xpath("/env:Envelope/env:Header/equipmentType/text()='WCA'")
    //.when(body().contains("WCA"))
    .to("activemq-ext-out:topic:" + topicName);
```

and my message never arrived in my out topic :( if i uncomment the when clause, and comment the filter, my message is correctly send, but i want to use filter

can someone help me how to find the good xpath expression?

possibly i can use .choice().when(xpath...).to(...)?

i just need a correct solution :)

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a namespace prefix issue. You're qualifying Envelope with "env:" which is good as long as that prefix is mapped to the right namespace. However, you are missing a suitable qualifier on equipmentTest which is in a different namespace.

See the [Camel docs](https://camel.apache.org/xpath.html) on how to configure a namespaces.

```
Namespaces ns = new Namespaces("ct", "http://com/fr/test")
    .add("env", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");

from("activemq-ext-in:queue:" + queueName)
   .id("amq-transfert-downward-route")
   .filter(
      ns.xpath("/env:Envelope/env:Header/ct:equipmentType/text()='WCA'")
   ).to("activemq-ext-out:topic:" + topicName);
```

Updated: changed to use the OP example instead of the one from the Camel docs. I haven't tested this but it looks about right.

Comment: ok i see but did you know how can i set the correct xpath value with the good ns?

Comment: ok; i see but me i need to test the value not an attribute, so i can use @..., i test with /c:equipmentType/text()='WCA' but not working, an idea?

Comment: my example wasn't your exact solution but rather a snippet from the docs for you to review. I'll edit and provide your exact solution.

Comment: In fact i have try this but i m using servicemix, and i don t know why but my bundle wasn't updated :( now its work like a charm! i can use /env:Envelope/env:Header/ct:equipmentType/text()='WCA' or 'TEST' too :)